# How to compute X week days into the past, using Python or SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, datetime

I need to compute exactly 5 week days into the past. e.g. if today's date is 2015-05-07 I need my program to give me 2015-04-30.

So far I tried is this

```
today = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(5)
```

This gives 5 days exactly into the past. But I need 5th weekday into the past.
The purpose I need this is because I have a database table which consists of some data and I need to write a Python script which fetches the data for last 5 days.

Comment: in mysql: `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)`

Comment: in transact sql : DATEADD(day, -5, CURDATE())

Comment: @JeremyC., that's not regular SQL. Perhaps MS SQL?

Comment: was transact, my bad I edited it works for sql server 2008 and newer and azure SQL db

Comment: What about national holidays? Are they supposed to counted or not? Weekdays according to which region?

Comment: SELECT * FROM  `mytable` WHERE DATE = DATEADD(day, -5, CURDATE()). This is giving 'DATEADD does not exist' error. I am using mysql server 5.5.38. is my swl server outdated? do ihave to update it?

Comment: weekdays according to india(IST). we don need to worry about national holidays coz the table has date for each weekday in an year.

Comment: So there's now in python to do this. is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `datetime` objects have a `isoweekday()` method to help with this.  This method returns a numeric value corresponding to the day of the week. So for example, Monday is the integer 1. You want to skip Saturday and Sunday, these correspond to 6 and 7 respectfully. We can use this to backtrack:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta                                              

def workingday(d, no_of_days):                                                              
    backdate = d                                                                      
    count = 0                                                                         
    while count < no_of_days:                                                                  
        backdate = backdate - timedelta(1)                                              
        if backdate.isoweekday() in (6,7):                                            
            continue                                                                  
        count += 1                                                                    
    return backdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


d = datetime.strptime("2015-05-07","%Y-%m-%d")                                        
print workingday(d, 5)

Output:

2015-04-30
```

I have used your date format. But you can easily change this.

Instead of `isoweekday()` you can use `weekday()` but now Monday will be returned as 0 and Sunday will be returned as 6.

Comment: Thanks finally i got some help in python.

Answer (score 2):

Five days in the past is simply:

```
select date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 5 day)
```

If by *week* day you mean Mon - Fri, then the logic is actually rather simple.  5 *week* days are one week, which is 7 days (at least in the United States).  So the answer to your question is

```
select date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 7 day)
```

Note that other numbers of days would require more complex logic, using `CASE`.